Please help me read the embroidered text on this fan sleeve


Picked this up long ago from an Australian dealer in Chinese textiles

First image:

五湖烟Ｘ（水）潤（闊），【⿱人口】（何）【⿱雨Ｘ】（處）浣春紗

Second image, top:

紅粉【⿰氵⿱Ｘ而】（溪）【⿰辵Ｘ】（邊）石，年年漾【⿱艹⿰氵吝】（落）【⿱艹Ｘ】（花）

These two lines belong to a poem, but the lines are reversed. The poet's name is unknown.

紅粉溪邊石，年年漾落花。
At the stones by the Lovers' Creek, fallen blossoms drift year after year
五湖烟水闊，何處浣春紗？
Amid the wide waters and vast mists of the Five Lakes, where might silk cloths be cleansed?


Second image, bottom:

暗水流花經（徑），春星帶艸堂

Line from Dù Fǔ of Táng's 《夜宴左氏莊》 (Evening Banquet at the Manor of Clan Zuǒ).

The quiet stream flows beside the flower-cradled path; the stars of a spring evening illuminates the cottage.


I'm sorry to say, this isn't a good piece of craft. The characters are barely legible - at least 1/3 of them are written incorrectly, some of it is in Simplified Chinese (unreadable in seal script shapes), and another 1/3 are very distorted.

page 1 玉湖烟雨润X,XX青楼, I guess,when I wrote down X it means I'm not sure.it means the lake scenery is very beautiful, like jade, the rain is very small and dense like smoke, very beautiful scenery is written in refined language.
